# Unable to compile typescript, very old versions and can't upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

I have no idea how to solve this. gulp has been installed. npm install ts-node@0.7.3 as well
angular is 2.4.10 so node is 6.9.5 and typescript is 2.0.10

npm run build.dev

> gulp build.dev --color

> [15:31:10] Requiring external module ts-node/register

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
> gulpfile.ts (1,23): Cannot find module 'gulp'. (2307)

Comment: Could you check if gulp is installed? Probably gulp --version should do for this.

Comment: CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1